# PHP - Call object methods dynamically via variables

Tags: php

I am trying to unit-test some of my code and it would be easier to just call my setters dynamically based on some variables. Unfortunately my approach does not work as expected and I couldn't find more information regarding on how to do that.

I have one variable which always is a string. It is used as property name and together with the "set" keyword it should result in "setSomething" or "setSomethingElse".

I already tried

```php
$obj->set{$property}($value);
// or
$obj->set$property($value);
```

But those do not seem to work.

Maybe someone of you pro's know the right approach ;)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the entire method name a variable, or enclose the whole name in `{}` e.g.

```
class test {
    public $Something;
    public $SomethingElse;

    function setSomething($value) {
        $this->Something = $value;
    }

    function setSomethingElse($value) {
        $this->SomethingElse = $value;
    }

}

$property = "Something";

$t = new test;
$setter = "set$property";
$t->$setter(4);
echo $t->Something;

$property = "SomethingElse";
$t->{"set$property"}(8);
echo $t->SomethingElse;
```

Output

```
4
8
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/aO5Vl)

Comment: Ah cool also what I've noticed is that PHP really does not care about lower/upper case. My properties are all lowercased but the setters still work. PHP Magic x), thank you still.

Comment: @TheKeymaster You can also use `$this->{'set' . $property}($value)` in one statement (don't think this deserves another answer).

Comment: @Jeto thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer to include that method.

Comment: @TheKeymaster yeah, PHP only cares about case with variable names. It's one of it's more annoying features (personally I wish it was case sensitive throughout).